# Parse Comments / Annotations From PDF Using .NET Version of PDFBox: PDFBox.NET-1.8.9

Tags: parsing, text, pdfbox

I am using the following code to parse text from a PDF using the .NET version of PDFBox.

```
Imports org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel
Imports org.apache.pdfbox.util

Private Shared Function parseUsingPDFBox(ByVal input As String) As String
      Dim doc As PDDocument = Nothing

      Try
        doc = PDDocument.load(input)
        Dim stripper As New PDFTextStripper()
        Return stripper.getText(doc)
      Finally
        If doc IsNot Nothing Then
          doc.close()
        End If
      End Try
    End Function
```

http://www.squarepdf.net/how-to-convert-pdf-to-text-in-net-vb

The code is extracting the plain visible text, but is not extracting the comments.

I have tried using FDFAnnotation.ToString() But it warns that ToString() is ambiguous...

```
doc = PDDocument.load(strFilename)
Dim stripper As New FDFAnnotationText
Return stripper.tostring(doc)
```

I have tried iTextSharp and with this I can extract them using PdfName.ANNOTS class, but wish to stick with PDFBox.

My preferred language is VB, but I am happy to accept answers in C# too.

Comment: It's also trivial to do that using PDFBox. You use VB but have not mentioned the exact .Net language anywhere. Does that mean that C# code would be ok, too?

Comment: Thanks @mkl I have modified the question to include the .NET version and added that although my preferred language is VB, I am happy to receive answers in C# too.

Comment: Hi @mkl I know you said it was 'trivial to do that using PDFBox'.  I have searched further but am still drawing a blank.  I am looking here for inspiration: https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.5/javadocs/index.html?org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/interactive/annotation/PDAnnotation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by "comments" you mean *text annotations* with **Name** value **Comment**. The following code outputs the **Contents** of all text annotations. If you mean a different annotation kind, you might have to adapt it:

```vb
Dim doc As PDDocument = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(New java.io.File("..."), Nothing)
Dim pages As java.util.List = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages()
For i = 0 To pages.size() - 1
    Dim page As PDPage = pages.get(i)
    Dim annotations As java.util.List = page.getAnnotations()
    For j = 0 To annotations.size() - 1
        Dim annotation As PDAnnotation = annotations.get(j)
        If annotation.getSubtype() = "Text" Then
            Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1} : {2}", i, j, annotation.getContents())
        End If
    Next
Next

doc.close()
```